# Some sort of text field - table view

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I'm wondering how I can get something like the image above. How do you make this and does anybody got some sort of sample code?

Comment: That is `UITextField` added into `UITableViewCell` subclass. CUSTOM TABLEVIEWCELL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design your custom cell(use custom font for your labels to get that exact appearance if necessary.)

Custom cell design

[image]

And customize the Cell for row at index delegate method like this.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    //    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    //    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //    if (cell == nil) {
    //        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //    }
    //    
        // Configure the cell...

        //Customiztion of  cell 
        static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cell";
        SampleTableCell *cell = (SampleTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSString *customeCellName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[SampleTableCell class]];

            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:customeCellName owner:self options:nil];

            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
                {
                    cell =  (SampleTableCell *) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cell.label1.text = @"Server";
        cell.label2.text = @"vereist"
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: I'm using storyboards

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a custom cell for your table, design your cell what ever you want. Put textView or any thing, and load your table with that custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

It is called custom `UITableViewCell`, There are consist of Two Controls

```
1 UILabel 
2 UITextField
```

Put this two control in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with Specific fram size.

**OR**

Put This Whole code as it is.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tblView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - 23) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tblView.delegate = self;
    self.tblView.dataSource = self;
    self.tblView.backgroundView = nil;
    self.tblView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tblView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tblView];

    self.placeHolderValue = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"server ", @"account", @"Roof Coverings", @"Wall token", @"Roof", @"Floor", @"Guttering",  nil];


    self.textFields = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.textLabels = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < self.placeHolderValue.count; i++)
    {
        UITextField *textFiled = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(155.0, 0.0, 150.0, 44.0)];
        textFiled.placeholder = @"Vereist";
        textFiled.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        textFiled.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        textFiled.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        textFiled.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        textFiled.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
        textFiled.delegate = self;
        textFiled.tag = i+1;
        textFiled.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        if (self.listOfDetails.count > 0)
        {
            textFiled.text = [[self.listOfDetails objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:[self.dbFieldName objectAtIndex:i]];
            isEmpty = NO;
        }
        [self.textFields addObject:textFiled];

        UILabel *lab = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 140, 44)];
        lab.text = [self.placeHolderValue objectAtIndex:i];
        lab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        lab.numberOfLines = 0;
        lab.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        lab.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.textLabels addObject:lab];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.placeHolderValue.count;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self.textLabels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self.textFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```